# как в android webview сделать чтобы ссылки открывались в другой приложений

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

Как в `android webview` сделать так чтобы ссылки типа `whatsapp` открывались в официальном приложений, чтобы `tel` открывал звонилку (телефон)?

Ну или чтобы `webview` приложение мог определить есть ли на телефоне это приложение и запустить?

Вот мой код:

```
package com.mixfood.talapker

import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.onesignal.OneSignal

const val ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "*********"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://site.com")

        // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE)

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this)
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

//            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
//                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
//                val cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)
//                val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
//                cookieManager.acceptCookie()
//                cookieManager.setCookie(url,cookies)
//                cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view,true)
//            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Через intent запускай дальше

Comment: как это сделать? можете в коде код сказать куда что писать. я пока новичок не понимаю вас. этот код еле как написал

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы открыть звонилку, вам нужно передавать в нее номер:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9999999999"));
startActivity(intent);
```

с WhatsApp выглядит все несколько по-другому, потому что нужно учитывать что у пользователя может не быть этой программы, в базовом варианте это делается так:

```
public static void setClickToChat(View v,String toNumber){
    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + toNumber;
    try {
        PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        v.getContext().startActivity(i);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
    }
}
```

вот есть [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422300/how-to-open-whatsapp-using-an-intent-in-your-android-app) где описывается как реализовать подобный функционал и вот [документация](https://faq.whatsapp.com/511210730860677/?cms_platform=android)

Comment: ему надо ещё описать перехватчик этих урлов в вэбвью